# Will an only-online checking account work for a new worker? (18 years old)

Tags: banking, online-banking, checking-account

I am completely new to opening banking accounts and using checks and all of that. I just got a job at McDonald's and I can get paid with a money card (not sure what that is yet) until I open a checking account. I was researching and found out there are banks that are entirely online. It sounds too good to be true to have a bank without any fees or confusion. I am just not sure how it would work when I get a check. I was reading an article that said you would somehow snap a picture of it, scan it, something like that. If I need to just open an account with a local bank I can do that too but if I can open one with an online bank that would be great. Thanks for any replies, and I am new to this site so sorry if this is in the wrong section or something like that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I can get paid with a money card

A money card is like a Debit Card, but is funded directly from your paycheck.  **Watch for usage fees, minimum balance fees, check cashing fees, etc, etc, etc.**

Definitely open a checking account at a local bank.

> It sounds too good to be true to have a bank without any fees or confusion.

There *are* banks in your area which have zero-fee, zero-minimum balance checking accounts for "young people".  Typically, that's "age 25 and under".

Even "regular" checking and savings accounts can be zero-fee, zero-minimum balance if you follow certain conditions like minimum balance or **two direct paycheck deposits per month.**

> I was reading an article that said you would somehow snap a picture of it, scan it, something like that.

That's done via a smartphone app provided by your bank.  It's *super useful*.

McDonald's should have Direct Deposit into your checking account (which you'll need to configure), though, so you won't use it frequently.

Some last things:

1. watch your money like a hawk (someone might steal your identity and clean you out; the sooner you notice it, the sooner you can tell the bank and get your money back),
2. never spend more than you have,
3. in fact, **spend less than you have** (something might come up which you need to buy *now*),
4. you're flush with cash now, but there *will* be expenses later,
5. open a savings account at an online bank, and transfer a "big" chunk of every paycheck to it every payday.  (We can't say what "big" is, because we don't know your situation.)

If I sound like a parent lecturing a teenager... it's because I gave my kids the same speech.  :)

Comment: This is actually really informative, I will go tomorrow and talk with them about opening an account. I am thinking about opening an online savings account with Ally, seems really popular and it gets good reviews. Thank you!

Comment: @AnthonyCararini Ally just happens to be where my online savings accounts are.